# Проблемка с нажатием на кнопку

Tags: java, eclipse

Здравствуйте. Я пишу приложение при помощи eclipse. И недавно столкнулся с
Ошибкой ,уже неделю голову ломаю над ней. Вот её суть :
Мне нужно по нажатию на кнопку изменить значение переменной, c true на false.
Я не могу этого сделать.Вот код:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_plus);

    final Button proverits = (Button)findViewById(R.id.proverka);

    boolean canpressbutton = true;

        ...

    proverits.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v) {
           if (canpressbutton) {
                int hmta = 0;
                canpressbutton=false;

                    ...

                String alt = ctpl(hmta);
                CharSequence to = alt.toString();
                proverits.setText(to);
            }
        }
    });
   }
```

(Ошибка на 13-ой строке: Cannot refer to the non-final local variable canpressbutton defined in an enclosing scope, на 15-ой такая же)

Если я напишу на 7-ой строке

```
final boolean canpressbutton = true;
```

то ошибка на 13-ой строке исчезнет, но появится новая на 15-ой строке :
The final local variable canpressbutton cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type

Заранее спасибо=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо переменные, на которые ругается компилятор перенести на уровен класса, т.е. сделать их полями класса, а не локальными переменными метода

Comment: А дело тут в замыканиях.